# python txt file to multiple txt files

Tags: python-3.x

I have a single txt file which contains multiple data samples in the form

> ID-001
>
> some data
>
> ID-002
>
> some other data
>
> ID-003
>
> some more data

and so on. Everything separated with an ID-i is a new data set, the IDs are unique, and the file is about 2000 lines.

I want to create a python script that will open the first file and create MULTIPLE txt files which will contain everything between ID-(i-1) to ID-i no matter how many different data samples there are in the file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/UCZVEx/1/) like so:

```
import re
pat=r'^(ID-\d+)$([\s\S]+?)(?=(?:^ID-\d+)|\Z)'
with open(ur_file) as f:
    for m in re.finditer(pat, f.read(), flags=re.M):
        print(f'{m.group(2)}' )
```

Prints:

```
some data



some other data



some more data
```

`m.group(1)` will have the `ID-xxx` and you could use that to write each block into a file.

Or, you can split the block into data blocks like so:

```
import re
with open(ur_file) as f:
    print([b for b in re.split(r'^ID-\d+', f.read(), flags=re.M) if b])
```

Prints:

```
['\nsome data\n\n', '\nsome other data\n\n', '\nsome more data\n']
```

Or you can use `re.findall` like so:

```
import re

pat=r'^(ID-\d+)$([\s\S]+?)(?=(?:^ID-\d+)|\Z)'
with open(ur_file) as f:
    print(re.findall(pat, f.read(), flags=re.M))
```

Prints:

```
[('ID-001', '\nsome data\n\n'), ('ID-002', '\nsome other data\n\n'), ('ID-003', '\nsome more data\n')]
```

Again, you can use that tuple data to write into separate files.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!